# Macro to combine selected workseets using checkboxes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm still very new to VBA and I was wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

I have several worksheets in the same workbook and I'm trying to select the worksheets by using check boxes, each of which corresponds to a particular worksheet, and then clicking a button to create a new worksheet with all data from each of the selected separate worksheets. Ie.,:

```
Worksheet 1:
column1      column2      column3
A            B            C
D            E            F

         +

Worksheet 2:
column1      column2      column3
G            H            I
K            L            O

         =

New Worksheet:
column1      column2      column3
A            B            C
D            E            F
G            H            I
K            L            O
```

the selected worksheets into one new worksheet. All the worksheets have the same structure (same number of columns, headers, etc). Worksheet 1 and Worksheet 2 above would be those that were selected by a user checking check boxes.

The worksheets are:

- IT Certification,
- Business Skills & Productivity,
- Database and Cybersecurity

and in this case I'm trying to store them in variables depending upon whether the check box that refers to them has been clicked:

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ITCert As Worksheet
Dim BSProd As Worksheet
Dim DC As Worksheet

If Me.CheckBox1 = True Then
    ITCert = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IT Certification")
End If

If Me.CheckBox2 = True Then
    BSProd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Business Skills & Productivity")
End If
If Me.CheckBox3 = True Then
    DC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database and Cybersecurity")
End If
End Sub
```

I'm not quite certain how to combine these sheets. Do I need to create a loop (I'm thinking no because a user would already select the sheets in question by clicking the check boxes). I was thinking of somehow adding the variables I've assigned the worksheets to together, but I've been unable to make this work.

Any help/suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I read the first two paragraphs of your question and I thought to myself, “Sure, that sounds reasonable.”  Then I read “The worksheets are … and … I'm trying to store them in variables”, and I started scratching my head.  It sounds like what you want to do is create a fourth worksheet, and then ***copy*** some or all of the first three into the fourth.

Comment: Hi Scott, sorry that I was unclear. You are exactly correct, I'm trying to copy all of the worksheets selected by the check boxes into a new worksheet (this would not be all the worksheets in the workbook, but only those that have been selected).

Comment: Well, then, I’m not sure that this `ITCert = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IT Certification")` business makes sense. I would suggest something more like `If Me.CheckBox1 Then` `(copy "IT Certification" sheet)` `End If` If Me.CheckBox2 Then` `(copy "Business Skills & Productivity" sheet)` `End If`, …. You could improve your question by explaining what you mean by “combine”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store objects in variables you have to use the "Set" command. 

I.e.:

```
Set ITCert = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IT Certification")
```

A simple copy can look like this, but you should better use the "names" for the source-sheets instead of numbers:
Code edited: Due to your comment !

```
Option Explicit  'use only clearly defined variables

Public Sub Test()
Dim r As Long
Dim rcnt As Long
Dim Dst As Worksheet
Dim chk1 As Boolean
Dim chk2 As Boolean

With ThisWorkbook
Set Dst = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))

'r = 2
rcnt = 1  ' stores amount of inserted rows
chk1 = True 'simulate checkbox1
chk2 = True 'simulate checkbox2

If chk1 Then
With .Sheets(1)                             
r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last source-row
.Range("A1:E" & r).Copy _
Destination:=Dst.Range("A" & rcnt)
rcnt = rcnt + r 'lastrow
End With                                    
End If

If chk2 Then
With .Sheets(2)                             
r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last source-row
.Range("A1:E" & r).Copy _
Destination:=Dst.Range("A" & rcnt)
rcnt = rcnt + r 'lastrow
End With                                    
End If

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, busybite, the above code works except for one problem. Only the first row of each sheet get combined into the new sheet, so there a total of 2 rows on the new sheet and not a total of all the rows. I suppose the "r" variable is set to "2", but each sheet has a different number of rows.

Comment: You're welcome. Range A1 to E(r=2) has been copied. I edited the code to find the last row in column A. Take care that there are no empty rows between the source-rows.

Comment: Thanks again. One quick question, and I know this is beyond the original question I asked. Do you know if it’s possible to delete rows that have duplicates on a single column, say, column D, so there would only be rows that have unique values in column D?